# FB.XFBML.parse() Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm using the FB comments plugin on a site that is built with jquery mobile. So the page that displays the comments is appended to a div. to get the comments to show up I have to use FB.XFBML.parse() and that works great! So then I make a comment and go to Facebook and click on the link. It brings me back to my site with this link: http://m.cabinquest.us/cabin/641/Georgenes+Haven/?fb_action_ids=10204622989792127&fb_action_types=og.comments. the comments show up but I get the "“Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined” error message and my site no longer works. If I take FB.XFBML.parse() out of the code. the link from facebook works.

So here's my code after the body tag:

```
        <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id))
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=MyAppID&version=v2.0";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and here is what I do in generating the page.

```
   div += '<div class="ui-corner-all custom-infobox">';
div += '<div class="ui-body ui-body-a">';
div += '<div id="fb-comments" class="fb-comments" data-href="http://m.cabinquest.us/cabin/' + data[0].id + '/' + title + '/" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
div += '</div>';
div += '</div><br>';

$('#content').html(div);

FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Comment: You can't call FB.XFBML.parse() because the javascript in the body tag loaded the sdk. You have to add an onload function. It is described in the Facebook docs

Comment: If I add an onload function what do I put in it? I searched facebook but couldn't find other ways of rendering the comments.

Comment: You use window.fbAsyncInit

Comment: I ended up rewriting this site to be server side and it eliminated the need to do this.